# ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web Application: error after updating to EF 6.0.2

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dynamic-data

ManyToMany_Edit.ascx:

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext' to System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext'
```

Error in code:

```
 ds.ContextCreated += (_, ctxCreatedEnventArgs) => ObjectContext = ctxCreatedEnventArgs.Context;
```

Note: I did what is required in `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/upgradeEF6`
this is the result..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the latest Dynamic Data Nuget

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/01/30/announcing-preview-of-dynamic-data-provider-and-entitydatasource-control-for-entity-framework-6.aspx